# Is there luggage reclaim before passport control for a transit at CDG, Paris?

Tags: transit, luggage, cdg, ukrainian-citizens

We are heading from Kyiv to Paris (Charles de Gaulle), and then from Paris to Marrakech (by different airlines, the first one is Ukrainian one and the last one is British, easyJet). Some of us don't have a visa for Paris, so I am interested:

is it possible to transit without going through the passport control in Paris, considering that our luggage won't be automatically re-registered for the next flight (i.e., is there luggage claim in the transit zone in Paris)?

Comment: I'm assuming you are travelling with Ukrainian citizens, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Is this on one ticket, or two tickets? (I'd guess two if EasyJet?)

Comment: Those are two tickets: one from Ukraine to Paris and the other one from Paris to Marrakech (only this one is easyJet). And our airline (the Ukrainian one) warned us that it's not possible for the luggage to be automatically transfered.

Comment: I'd say it's time to start practising travelling with hand baggage only then... That or cancel those tickets and buy some where luggage can be through-checked#

Answer (score 9):

No. You will need to go through passport control in Paris and enter the Schengen zone, collect your bags, and re-check them in at the EasyJet counter, and exit the Schengen zone again.

EasyJet does not have luggage interline agreements with other airlines and will not accept interline baggage from them, even if they are so tagged.

EasyJet also enforces carry on baggage limitations.

If you are feeling brave, you could ask a member of the Paris airport to take care of the transit of your bags when you arrive. But at CDG, with EasyJet, in my personal experience I think this is quite unlikely to work and your bags will be stuck in Paris.

Your best option is to pack light! Alternatively, perhaps one of you can enter France and take care of the checked bags under his/her own name.